# Line Integral with Change of Variables

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, change-of-variable

I'm a bit rusty on my computational math, and genuinely can't solve this question which is frustrating me.

**QUESTION:**

$$\int_Csin(y)dx+xcos(y)dy$$ where C is the ellipse defined as follows: $x^2+xy+y^2=1$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Define variable $u= \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}x+\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}y}$

Define variable $v= \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}x-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}y$

Hence:

$u^2+v^2=(\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}x+\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}y})^2+(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}x-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}y)^2$

$=(\frac{3}{4}x^2+\frac{(2)(3)}{4}xy+\frac{3}{4}y^2)+(\frac{1}{4}x^2-\frac{2}{4}xy+\frac{1}{4}y^2)$

$=(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4})x^2+(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2})xy+(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4})y^2$

$=(x^2+xy+y^2) = C$

Therefore, we have Jacobian:
$$     
       \begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} \\
       \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} & \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} \\
       \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$     
       \begin{bmatrix}
       \sqrt\frac{3}{4} & \sqrt\frac{3}{4} \\
       \sqrt\frac{1}{4} & -\sqrt\frac{1}{4} \\
       \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$

Beyond this point, I must incorporate the original dot product with the differential $(dx,dy)$ but don't know how

Comment: The Jacobian is good if you are doing an area integral. Not sure if you need the Jacobian for this line integral problem.

Comment: I believe Green's theorem is needed here. I mean perhaps you could do the line integral problem directly, however, that lead to trouble for me. I got much farther, albeit still stuck, with this approach

Comment: Must I take the reciprocal of my fraction, that is: $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, it has been sometime since I've done change of variables.

Comment: It looks like you missed a sign in your Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Fixed. thx for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x\cos\left(y\right)\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\sin\left(y\right)\right)&=\cos\left(y\right)-\cos\left(y\right)=0
\end{align*}

Comment: wow, by Green's theorem the line integral is simply zero.... wow... This whole time finding a parametrization was wasted. I appreciate this a lot. cheers

Comment: The integral theorems can be very useful as you have two equivalent problems and you can choose which one to solve. At times, the problem is trivial to solve once you cast it into another integral (via Green's theorem or Stokes' theorem or the divergence theorem, whichever is potentially appropriate for the given problem).

Answer (score 1):

The integral is path independent because

$$\nabla(x\sin y) = (\sin y, x\cos y)$$

So, the integral along the closed contour $C$ vanishes:

$$\int_C (\sin y\,dx + x\cos y\,dy) =0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use Green's theorem instead to ease out calculations:

$\int_C Pdx+Qdy=\int\int_R (\partial Q/\partial x-\partial P/\partial y) dx dy$

where $R$ is the region bounded by closed curve $C$ on $xy-$ plane oriented counterclockwise.